# Doctrine: avoid collision in update

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a product table accesed by many applications, with several users in each one. I want to avoid collisions, but in a very small portion of code I have detected collisions can occur.

```
$item = $em->getRepository('MyProjectProductBundle:Item')
           ->findOneBy(array('product'=>$this, 'state'=>1));

if ($item)
{
    $item->setState(3);
    $item->setDateSold(new \DateTime("now"));
    $item->setDateSent(new \DateTime("now"));

    $dateC = new \DateTime("now");
    $dateC->add(new \DateInterval('P1Y'));
    $item->setDateGuarantee($dateC);

    $em->persist($item);
    $em->flush();

   //...after this, set up customer data, etc.
}
```

One option could be make 2 `persist()` and `flush()`, the first one just after the state change, but before doing it I would like to know if there is a way that offers more guarantee.

I don't think a transaction is a solution, as there are actually many other actions involved in the process so, wrapping them in a transaction would force many rollbacks and failed sellings, making it worse.

Tha database is Postgress.

Any other ideas?

Comment: if you are getting the item from the repository persisting it again will attempt to insert it again. After retrieving the item you can change item settings then you only need to call flush() to update them. You only need to call persist() if you are trying to save a new one.

Comment: I didn't know this, this will be my short term solution, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought would be to look at [optimistic locking](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#optimistic-locking).  The end result is that if someone changes the underlying data out from under you, doctrine will throw an exception on flush.  However, this might not be easy, since you say you have multiple applications operating on a central database -- it's not clear if you can control those applications or not, and you'll need to, because they'll all need to play along with the optimistic locking scheme and update the version column when they run updates.

Comment: I don't have control over those applications, but this is not a bad approach. I mean, in short term is not a solution for me, as I don't have control over the apps or even over the database, but it may be a good approach for future versions of these apps. Thanks